# Stripe subscription cancel: KeyError 'HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

I'm trying to configure Django Stripe Subscriptions for WebApp.

I want to let Subscribed users cancel the subscription themselves.

The code below is to delete user's information from StripeAPI and Django StripeCustomer model.

Here is view.py

```
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  
from django.http.response import JsonResponse, HttpResponse  
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from subscriptions.models import StripeCustomer 

@login_required    
@csrf_exempt
def cancel_subscription(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:

        endpoint_secret = settings.STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET
        payload = request.body
        event = None
        sig_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
       
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
        payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
        )
        session = event['data']['object']

        stripe_customer = StripeCustomer.objects.get(user=request.user)
        stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
        sub_id = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(stripe_customer.stripeSubscriptionId)
        client_reference_id = session.get('client_reference_id')
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=client_reference_id)

        try:
            #delete from stripeapi
            stripe.Subscription.delete(sub_id)

            #delete from StripeCustomer model
            StripeCustomer.objects.delete(
            user=user,
            stripeCustomerId=stripe_customer_id,
            stripeSubscriptionId=stripe_subscription_id,
            )
            print(user.username + ' unsubscribed.')
        except Exception as e:
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()
            return JsonResponse({'error': (e.args[0])}, status =403)
    
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

When I excecute the code error occuerd at

**sig_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']**

The error message is below

**Exception Type: keyError**

**Exception Value: 'HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'**

I don't understand why the error occurs at request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'],because other part of this view can execute this code.

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you

Comment: I just came across this error today due to the incorrect STRIPE_SECRET_KEY.

After correct that from strike's webhook settings, the error is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing up a webhook handler and a regular POST request route as part of your application here.  You either need one or the other, and I suspect you don't need the webhook stuff at all given what you're trying to to.

Comment: The problem was solved because of your advice.
Thank you very much.